# Can't get a basic Selenium + Capybara + Cucumber to work on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber, bdd

Ok, I've been using `selenium`, etc for `rails 2` projects, I've been working on for a while.  Deciding to refactor AS I move the app to `Rails 3`, I've been trying to set up a very basic `Rails 3` project with cucumber and capybara, and then run a test with selenium.  (I'm using selenium because I know for a fact that some of my feature tests required me to use selenium to get the proper javascript interactions to work.)

I set things up plain jane, have all the gems installed, ran the `cucumber installer` with the --`capybara` - the whole nine yards.  Yet when I include `@selenium` in a test I get:

```
When I go to the home page     # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:23
  Selenium is not a module (TypeError)
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:24:in `/^(?:|I )go to (.+)$/'
  features/access.feature:10:in `When I go to the home page'
```

Why am I getting this Selenium is not a module error?  I know it means it's not loaded, but I've gone back over my steps three times and can't figure out why this is coming up.  Anyone have leads on what I should be checking?

Again, this is rails 3. I'm on ruby 1.9.2 with this project.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welp, found the answer.  I had neglected to install selenium-client gem and require selenium/client in the env.rb.

All better now.  Just needed a day off to think it through.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me some digging.  It's perfectly okay to accept your own answer.  It will help others find the solution in the future, and you earned it :)